# Can't get an Apache CustomLog to work

Tags: apache

I'm trying to create a CustomLog directive for my httpd.conf file. The directives I've inserted are

```
LogFormat "%h %t %t %{Referer}i" testx
CustomLog /var/www/httpd-logs/example.com.access.log testx
```

I have %t twice so I can see the log entry easier if it comes through. But it doesn't.  All I see in the log for this is "testx" at the beginning of a line, with no additional data.

Also, I notice that the documentation for Apache logging puts quotes around %{Refered}i but if I do that, like

```
LogFormat "%h %t %t "%{Referer}i"" testx
```

ISP manager won't accept it into httpd.conf.

Finally, what I really want to log is the header Accept value (HTTP_ACCEPT), so I've tried making the LogFormat line

```
LogFormat "%h %t %t %{Accept}i" testx
```

but that doesn't work either.

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well first of all you have to escape those double quotes if you want to have them in there, like this:

```
LogFormat "%h %t %t \"%{Referer}i\"" testx
```

That said, your example works fine for me:

```
LogFormat "%h %t %t %{Referer}i" testx
CustomLog /example/path/example.com.access.log testx
```

Gave me (all forbidden entries just visiting the homepage of my test site):

```
1.2.3.4 [29/Jun/2017:23:25:20 +0000] [29/Jun/2017:23:25:20 +0000] -
1.2.3.4 [29/Jun/2017:23:25:20 +0000] [29/Jun/2017:23:25:20 +0000] http://www.example.com/
1.2.3.4 [29/Jun/2017:23:25:20 +0000] [29/Jun/2017:23:25:20 +0000] -
1.2.3.4 [29/Jun/2017:23:25:20 +0000] [29/Jun/2017:23:25:20 +0000] -
1.2.3.4 [29/Jun/2017:23:25:22 +0000] [29/Jun/2017:23:25:22 +0000] -
1.2.3.4 [29/Jun/2017:23:25:23 +0000] [29/Jun/2017:23:25:23 +0000] http://www.example.com/
```

Be sure you're not adding them in a `.htaccess` file and don't forget to restart Apache after making a change.